# How can I change my default Outlook account?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am trying to remove my current email account from outlook and add another one

I clicked on tools>account settings then removed my current account(gmail account) from the list of emails

Then I clicked on new and add my new account (hotmail account), but no messages loads from my new account and my old messages from the old email still there under personal folders!

Then I click on tools> account settings >data files and found personal folder as a defult file I tryed to remove it but I cant then I tried to set my new account as default but it didnt work

Answer (score 2):

1. Deleting an account in Outlook will not delete messages from your folders.
2. You cannot delete or move an account data folder while Outlook is running.

Have you tried sending a test email from you new account?

To move or delete the files, open your account details, under the "Data" tab, make a note of the location of your files, close Outlook and then delete or move the file.